# Customize Java 1.6 code to work in Java 1.3

Tags: java, string, version

`String.format("%,.2f", tranInfo.getAmount())`

Note : **tranInfo.getAmount()** return **double** type

the above Java code work fine in *Java version 1.6* in  **Windows** platform.

But when i try to customize the code to :

`String.format("%,.2f",new Object[] {new Double(tranInfo.getAmount())})`

in order to work with *Java version 1.3* in **Sco OpenServer 5.0.6** platform.

it always has an error on run-time with the method **String.format()**

*my question is :*

Any **String.format()** code to work with **(String,double)** in **java 1.3** ?

but Java 1.3 supports only **String.format(String,Object[])**

Thank in advance.

Comment: @John: An error is about 
`String.format("%,.2f",new Object[] {new Double(tranInfo.getAmount())})' is not supported by java 1.3

Comment: @Qudam: yes. You need Java 5 or above.

Comment: @John : you missed my point . i want a code with **String.format()** with support in java 1.3 .

Comment: `i want a code with String.format() with support in java 1.3 .` I suspect its because you **have to**, not that you **want to**. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 6 you are relying on varargs and auto-boxing to turn `double` into `Object[]`.  Varargs and autoboxing were introduced in Java 5.

Hypothetically, you could get String.format to work in Java 1.3 with a `double` argument, by doing the conversion explicitly; e.g.

```
String.format("%,.2f", new Object[]{new Double(tranInfo.getAmount()))});
```

This code would work in Java 1.3 and later versions ... except that String.format was only introduced in Java 1.5 too.

Now if you are somehow getting this to work, then you are not using something that is truly Java 1.3.x.  (Perhaps, SCO's Java is not true Java 1.3.x?  Perhaps you are compiling on Java 6 with -source set to 1.3?  In the latter case, you are likely to get errors when you run the code on Java 1.3.)

---

In general, there is no guarantee that code written for a newer version of Java will compile with an older version of Java.  Getting new code to run on an old platform will typically involve changing the code to avoid the use of newer language features and APIs.

---

SCO is effectively a dead platform ... killed by SCO's stupidity in trying to extort money from the Linux world.  You would be well advised to migrate your applications to something else.

Comment: I've already done this , but when i run the java application on **Sco OpenServer 5.0.6** platform , it still has an error on runtime.

Comment: This won't work. The `String#format()` method (the whole `Formatter` class actually) was introduced in Java 1.5 as well.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks . i tried `String.format("%,.2f", new Object[]{new Double(tranInfo.getAmount()))});` and compile the application for the second time.

Now it's working fine....

Comment: @Oudam: Then you're not targeting Java 1.3 at all. Perhaps you're confusing with Java 1.5? In the future, you should really be more clear about the error you got on runtime. Copypaste it instead of hiding it away behind "an error".

Comment: @BalusC: Thank brother for giving me advice and support to answer my question. i'm glad to show my error for next time.